# Doxygen Directory Structure in File List with FULL_PATH_NAMES = NO

Tags: c, doxygen

I do not want the full path names to appear in the include dependency graphs generated by Doxygen. Thus, I set `FULL_PATH_NAMES = NO` in my *.doxyfile, and the labels of header files in the dependency graph changed from `/really/long/path/to/source/tree/Directory 3/Directory 3B/File 3B-1.h` to simply `File 3B-1.h`, which is what I want.

However, upon doing this, Doxygen changed the way it displays the File List. Instead of consisting of a graphical, collapsible directory tree  with multiple display levels like the following...

```
+ Directory 1
+ Directory 2
- Directory 3
    + Directory 3A
    - Directory 3B
        File 3B-1.h
        File 3B-2.h
    File 3-1
    File 3-2
+ Directory 4
```

... it switched to a completely flattened display with files listed like the following...

```
/Directory 3/File 3-1
/Directory 3/File 3-2
/Directory 3/Directory 3B/File 3B-1.h
/Directory 3/Directory 3B/File 3B-2.h
```

Is there a way to change the behavior so that files in the dependency graphs appear as described in the first paragraph, but the File List appears as a directory tree?

Answer (score 0):

One way of partially achieving the functionality I'm looking for is to set `FULL_PATH_NAMES = YES` in the config file, and then set `STRIP_FROM_PATH = /really/long/path/to/source/tree/`.

This keeps the file list like I want it, but the header files in the dependency diagrams are now shown as `Directory 3/Directory 3B/File 3B-1.h` instead of just `File 3B-1.h` like I want.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and setting `STRIP_FROM_INC_PATH = src/` with `FULL_PATH_NAMES = YES` achieves the same result without having to set `STRIP_FROM_PATH` to an absolute path.

I am using input as `INPUT = ../src` so files are listed this way:

```
- src
    + Directory 1
    - Directory 2
        File 1
        File 2
```